# Querying a Temporary Table in NHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, database, nhibernate, icriteria

I have a process which generates a result set for me and stores it in a temporary table.  I have the name of the temporary table.  I am trying to find a way, using NHibernate, to create a DetachedCriteria against the temporary table.  To put it another way, I have a table **[Book]** which has a column, **[BookId]**.  I have a temporary table **[TempTableName]**, which has a column **[TempId]**.  I want to create a DetachedCriteria for the **[Book]** table, wherein all the **[Book]** s with **[BookId]** in **[TempTableName]** .**[TempId]** are returned.  Is there any way to do this, preferably with the Criteria API?  Especially given that the name of the temp table itself may vary from run to run?

Answer (score 1):

Hm, I'd say it should be possible and maybe even without extending/changing Hibernate/NHibernate.

You could introduce a class that maps the temporary table, but that table would only exist (sometimes) at runtime, so Hibernate's validation would probably complain at startup, unless you disable it, which is possible as far as i recall.

Have you tried mapping a class to a temporary table? The naming scheme of the temporary tables might be problematic in query generation. They will probably be specific to your RDBMS.

I guess that all these things can be solved by extending some Hibernate classes, but I have not tried.

Comment: NH does **not** validate that tables exist, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: What about the circumstance where the temporary table name changes on each run?

Comment: @GWLlosa that would indeed be a problem, but as far as i understood your original posting, the table name would be known.

Comment: It would be known, but not at compile time.  That is, the code leading up to this point would be able to determine the table name before calling nHibernate.

Comment: I guess that makes things more difficult. You should be able to alter some details of a pre-defined mapping at runtime though. I remember that this is possible in the Java version at least.